# What is the difference between public <T extends Animal> void addAll(List<T> animals) and public void addAll(List<Animal> animals)?

Tags: java, generics

I am a bit confused with this, so a bit of clarification would be appreciated.

```
public <T extends Animal> void addAll(List<T> animals)
```

vs.

```
public void addAll(List<Animal> animals)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is in which type parameters in the `List` will be accepted by the method.

In the first method, `T` can be `Animal` or any subclass, so `addAll` will accept a `List<Animal>`, a `List<Dog>`, or a `List<Cat>`.  Note that this signature is equivalent to

```
public void addAll(List<? extends Animal> animals)
```

when you don't need the exact type of `Animal` in the body of the method.

In the second method, you've specified that the type parameter must be `Animal`.  Java's generics are invariant, so no subtypes of `Animal` will be allowed.  This method will accept a `List<Animal>`, but not a `List<Dog>` or a `List<Cat>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also had similar answer in my mind, and needed to make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

in simple words 'T' is an object type. So List 'T" type can accept any type of object whereas List of type Animal will take elements of only Animal type and not any other object.

That's the advantage of using Generics.